# How can I make a bot join a specific voice channel? (discord.py)

Tags: bots, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot that, when called upon, will join the voice channel that the author is in.

Here's what I have:

```
@client.command(aliases=["join"])
async def join_voice(self, ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if channel:
        print(channel.id)
        await channel.connect()
```

When I join a voice channel and type the command I get this error:

```
Ignoring exception in command join_voice:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 790, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 751, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 670, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 516, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this command located in a cog/extension? It looks like the context is being passed as self, which is only needed if a function is a class function. If you are declaring this command in your main file you can just have the signature be 
`async def join_voice(ctx):`